# How to shift and mask bits from integer in Lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm porting an Objective-C iOS application to CoronaSDK which uses Lua. I have a **signed** 16-bit integer and I want to isolate the high and low bytes in it. In C you can simply do:

```
uint8_t a = (dx >> 8) & 0xff;
uint8_t b = dx & 0xff;
```

Lua has no bitwise operators. How can I do this in Lua? This is for a mobile application and external binary libraries to extend Lua would most likely not work in all devices, if any. Any pure Lua solutions to this problem that you could suggest?

Comment: Divide by 256 and take the remainer?

Comment: Lua 5.2 has a bit operations library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Lua but can give you a general idea. Right shift by n is equivalent to divide by 2^n. You can first divide by 2^8 = 256 to get the MSBs and then multiply and divide by 2^8 to get LSBs.

```
MSBs = dx / 256
LSBleftsifted = (ds * 256)
LSBs = LSBleftsifted / 256
```

This is considering that all this is an unsigned integer operation.

Comment: Ah, right! Thanks for the answer. I got two functions that work based on this. Posting as separate answer because I couldn't get the proper format in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ash answer, here are a couple of Lua functions. I'm sure they can be generalized, but this does what I needed:

```
local function getLowByte16( value )
    local high_value = math.floor(value/256)
    high_value = high_value*256
    local low_value = value - high_value
    return low_value
end

local function getHighByte16( value )
    local high_value = math.floor(value/256)
    return high_value
end
```

Comment: For `value == -1` you'll get `high == -1`, `low == 255`.  Is that what you need?  You may have to convert `value` to unsigned by `value = value % 65536` prior to calling your functions to get both results in range `0..255`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I take care of that before calling the methods by taking the complement: `if value < 0 then value = 0xffff + value end`

Comment: Why 0xffff?  It should be 0x10000